How to enhance sound quality in my ubuntu 24.04
How to enhance sound quality in my ubuntu 24.04
My device is HP 15 2R29NX
I previously used windows 10, and the sound in this laptop is good.
but after installing ubuntu, the sound quality is worse.
so how to increase / enhance it?
Thanks
